# Android upload picture freezes app

Tags: android, image, cordova, upload

We are running a hybrid Android app that uses Phonegap and some native functionality for things like credit card swiping, etc. Since our latest release we have seen an issue with the upload picture feature of the web application.

Basically, when you view the page in your mobile browser (not through the app) you can upload a picture just fine and save, everything works great. When you view the page through the native app, all functionality freezes after you select a photo to upload from your phone's photo gallery. Here is the order of things:

1. Go to My Profile page
2. Click "Change Picture" which displays upload picture widget
3. Choose file... select a photo on the phone's photo gallery
4. Freezes app

You can still scroll around on the page, but all links and functionality stops.

Running the debugger through Eclipse I do not see any warnings or flags popping up that would indicate an issue with the native code. Between hitting "choose file" and browsing for a photo to returning to the web screen, this is the log in Eclipse:

```
03-18 13:43:37.489: D/CordovaActivity(1693): Paused the application!
03-18 13:43:37.489: D/CordovaWebView(1693): Handle the pause
03-18 13:43:37.589: D/dalvikvm(1693): GC_CONCURRENT freed 663K, 46% free 3895K/7175K, external 0K/0K, paused 2ms+3ms
03-18 13:43:48.370: D/Whitelist(1693): Unlimited access to network resources
03-18 13:43:48.370: I/CordovaLog(1693): Found start page location: index.html
03-18 13:43:48.370: I/CordovaLog(1693): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
03-18 13:43:48.370: D/CordovaActivity(1693): Resuming the App
03-18 13:43:48.370: D/CordovaActivity(1693): CB-3064: The errorUrl is null
```

Here is the crash report from the Play store:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
at android.webkit.WebViewClassic$DateTimePicker.show(WebViewClassic.java:7682)
at android.webkit.WebViewClassic.displayDateTimePickers(WebViewClassic.java:7648)
at android.webkit.WebViewClassic.access$11800(WebViewClassic.java:276)
at android.webkit.WebViewClassic$PrivateHandler.handleMessage(WebViewClassic.java:13259)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I think you should rebuild this app natively, it would cause less stress :)

Comment: See this question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258795/the-android-app-crashes-when-trying-to-upload-a-picture-from-my-phone